How to integrate copilot studio with Twilio account with Azure Bot
we have requirement where we need to integrate copilot studio with Twilio account to set automatic reply for sms receive in Twilio.
when we get reply from what's we are getting below error message.
The URI scheme, of the URI null, must be equal (ignoring case) to 'http', 'https', 'ws', or 'wss'
thanks,
Rahman

The error message that you got may happen when Twilio tries to send an incoming message to an endpoint that’s not properly configured.
To integrate Azure Bot with Twilio
create and configure Bot Service.

set up a Twilio phone number for receiving SMS messages.

Configure Twilio webhook i.e. set a message comes in URL to whatever bot name you gave and ensure the HTTP method is set to POST. This URL is where Twilio will send incoming messages to your bot. If Twilio cannot reach the specified URL, check if it is set to null due to which you are getting that error
for example-
https://sms-reply-bot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages


and finally verify your Bot’s endpoint config
Uder settings > Channels > choose Twilio (SMS) and configure the channel as below

These details you will get from your twillio account dashboard. That's how you connect your bot with twillio.
Checkout- Publish a copilot to Azure Bot Service channels and Creating and Connecting Azure Bot with Twilio SMS
